# Google Sheets: Cannot add labels to a chart series

Tags: google-sheets, charts, google-sheets-charts

I have a [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KrSwSbJGvn5hW_8uQRlLeNsSszPG6ZFNdWk0y06Brdc/edit?usp=sharing) chart based on a simple dataset. Column A is the x-axis, column B is the series, and I would like to use column C as my labels for the series. You can see this below:

[image]

My understanding is that (and I have done that in the past) I can select the series, press the "3 dots" and click on "Add labels" so I can configure column C as the labels for the series, as shown below.

[image]

It turns out that when I click "Add labels", nothing happens. Has anyone seen this? It seems random since when I try simpler datasets, sometimes it works.

EDIT:
I removed the series, removed the x axis, and then removed the Data Range. Started from scratch, and then it allowed me to add labels.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour, I can add the labels successfully, even with a very similar dataset. After clicking `Add labels`, are you clicking `Select a data range` and selecting the desired data? I'm always getting the labels when doing this.

Comment: I removed the series, removed the x axis, and then removed the Data Range. Started from scratch, and then it allowed me to add labels.... go figure....